# Laravel 3 routing with URI keeps giving 404 error

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-404, laravel-routing

Need to use URI to send an id across in laravel 3. I know in L4 its {whatever} but I'm stuck with L3's (:any) for this project. I keep getting 404's as it's looking for it in a controller "quote" that doesn't exist - I need it to use Shipquote controller.

I've tried this:

```
Route::any('quotes/ship/view/(:any)', 'Shipquote@viewQuote');
```

...didn't work. I tried this as a test:

```
Route::any('quotes/ship/view/test', 'Shipquote@viewQuoteTest');
```

...that worked.

I Also tried:

```
Route::any('quotes/ship/view/(:any)', function($id)
{
 return Controller::call('Shipquote@viewQuote', array($id));
});
```

...didn't work either. Tried with Route::any, Route::get and Route::post but still get 404.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I just needed to go to bed. It worked the next day.....:S

Anyway, to give this post some credit here's a little bit of basic knowledge:

```
Dynamic routing in Laravel 3
          Route::any('some/path/and/(:any)', 'someController@someFunction');
          Route::any('some/path/and/(:num)', 'someController@someFunction');
          Route::any('some/path/and/(:all)', 'someController@someFunction');

Dynamic routing in Laravel 4
          Route::any('some/path/and/{$someval}', 'someController@someFunction');
```